# Использование переменных из формы в кнопке

Tags: c#

Начал недавно осваивать C#. Нужно сделать программу, которая бы угадывала число которое загадал пользователь. Пользователь может нажимать на кнопки "больше" или "меньше". Есть массив случайных чисел из которого случайным образом выбирается число. Не могу немного понять как запрограммировать кнопку "меньше", чтобы при её нажатии выводились числа из массива только те, которые меньше числа которое высветилось пользователю.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int[] array = new int[20];
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = rnd.Next(0, 20);

                label1.Text = array[new Random().Next(0, array.Length)].ToString();

            }
        }
```

Вот код выбора случайного числа из массива.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно сделать переменную `array` полем класса `Form1`, а также сделать загаданное число полем:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int[] array = new int[20];
    private Random pickRnd = new Random();
    private int pickedNumber;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rnd.Next(0, 20);
        }

        pickedNumber = PickNumber();
        label1.Text = pickedNumber.ToString();
    }

    private int PickNumber()
    {
        return array[pickRnd.Next(0, array.Length)];
    }
}
```

Тогда вы сможете обращаться к ним из других методов (в частности, из обработчиков нажатия кнопок):

```
private void btnLess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // оставляем только числа меньше загаданного
    array = array.Where(i => i < pickedNumber).ToArray();
    // загадываем новое число
    pickedNumber = PickNumber();
    label1.Text = pickedNumber.ToString();
}
```

С кнопкой "Больше" аналогично, только выбирать нужно бОльшие числа.

Comment: То есть, массив и переменную с рандомом нужно вынести перед формой ?

Comment: @Андрей за пределы *конструктора* формы. Обновил ответ.

Comment: А, всё. Я понял. Просто не посмотрел. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Андрей не за что.

Comment: А как его корректно вывести ? Вместо числа выводит system.int,32[]

Comment: @Андрей обновил ответ.

Comment: Можете назвать меня тупым, но с вашим кодом у меня просто выводит все числа из массива, которые меньше числа pickedNumber

Comment: @Андрей я как-то не так понял вашу фразу "чтобы при её нажатии выводились числа из массива только те, которые меньше числа которое высветилось пользователю"?

Comment: А, извиняюсь. Они должны по одному выводится. Вывелось 10, нажимаем меньше и оно выводит следующее число, которое меньше 10. Например, вывелось 7. Нажимаем меньше и снова оно выводит число, которое меньше 7. И так далее.

Comment: @Андрей понял. Обновил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: Более- менее. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть массив случайных чисел из которого случайным образом выбирается число.

Я бы не советовал использоивать этот алгоритм, тк он крайне нееффективен.
Рекомендую использовать алгоритм двоичного поиска, и всегда проверять границы допустимого диапозона(0,20)
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA

Comment: Там же просто обращение по индексу.

Comment: А если вы про "найти все числа меньше загаданного", то во-первых массив должен быть отсортирован для бинарного поиска, а во-вторых 20 элементов же. О какой неэффективности речь?

Comment: Ну, во первых человек учится, и способ предложенный им не лучшй для решения данной задачи. Я предложил более оптимальный алгоритм. А во вторых при использовании двоичного поиска ему массив вообще не понадобится, нужны лишь будут границы диапозона.